# Setting the text field using setText(..) method with a double value. Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I'm trying to use `setText(..)` and sending a double value to it but it says

```
setText(java.lang.String) in javax.swing.text.JTextComponent cannot be applied to (double)
```

Comment: The error cannot be any clearer.

Comment: Use `setText(String.valueOf(yourDouble));`

Comment: Thank you! it's working, using valueOf didn't come to my mind:)

Answer (score 7):

You need to convert your `double` to a `String` and then pass that `String` as an argument to the `setText(String)` method. This is how you convert a `double` to a `String`:

```
double d = 3.14;
String s = String.valueOf(d);
// s is now "3.14"
```